# How to share x axes into a loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I create plots using a loop and I would like these plots share their x axes. Hereafter is an example of the code. Of course, val and functions to plot are more complex. I would like all subplots share the x axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

val = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
nplots = len(val)
plt.figure()
for i, alpha in enumerate(val):
    plt.subplot(nplots,1,i+1)
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,100), a * np.linspace(0,1,100)**2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "share the x axes"?  You are clearly making different subplots.  If you mean having them span the same extent, you can set the limits of them explicitly with xlim().

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: All x axes will span the same extent (because of the data) but if plots share x axes, if I zoom in one plot it will zoom also in other and that is the behavior I would like to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the recipe example here might help:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html

In your context, how does this do?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = plt.subplot(nplots,1,1)
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,100), a * np.linspace(0,1,100)**2)
for i, alpha in enumerate(val):
    plt.subplot(nplots,1,i+2,sharex=ax0)
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,100), a * np.linspace(0,1,100)**2)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**
Updating my own answer with a more elegant solution the OP might like:

```
vals = np.linspace(0,1,3)
nplots = len(vals)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nplots, ncols=1, sharex=True)
for i, alpha in enumerate(vals):
    axs[i].plot(np.linspace(0,1,100), alpha * np.linspace(0,1,100)**2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not really, my problem is related to the loop. Do I must create a list of ax object ?

Comment: I don't think it should matter whether the subplots are created in a loop or not, but yes you will need to keep a reference to the ax object(s) in order to share them with each other.

Comment: Probably just keeping the first one to share with the others will do (as in the example)

Comment: I added some example mods to your code which I *think* does what you want

Comment: It does what I want, thanks. But if it was implemented, I would had prefer to set this option globally for example when I create the figure. It would be more elegant.

Comment: @Ger I know it's much later but I added a more elegant solution if you care to take a gander :)